# Ignore records between last thursday and this thursday not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored proceedure where a user passes in a payment type from a simple web application to return only those payment types.

For Credit Card payments I want to ignore any records that fall between thursday of last week and thursday of this week.

I have written this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, (DATEDIFF (day, 4, GETDATE()) / 7) * 7, 3) 
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(nvarchar(20), DATEADD(day, 4 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), GETDATE()), 103))
```

Which finds out the thursday of last week and the thursday of this week.

However when i use this in my stored Proc it still returns records between those dates.

This is the section of the stored proc where it is used

```
ELSE IF @PaymentType = 'Credit Card'
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT [Variable] 
      ,[Variable]
      ,[Variable]
      ,[Variable]
      ,[DueDate]
      ,[Variable]
      ,[Variable]
      ,[Variable]
      ,[Variable]
      ,[Variable]
      ,[Variable]
      ,[Variable]
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE  PaymentMethod = 'Credit Card' AND 
           [DueDate] NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(day, (DATEDIFF (day, 4, GETDATE()) / 7) * 7, 3) AND
           CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(nvarchar(20), DATEADD(day, 4 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), GETDATE()), 103))
    ORDER BY DueDate desc   
END
```

This is a screenshot of some of the data (cant show any more due to data protection)
[image]

For the way i want it to work it shouldn't be returning these records (they are wednesday of current week which i want to ignore)

I cant figure out why its returning these so any help would be appriciated

Comment: Are you using the correct setting for which day the week starts? You can check with `SELECT @@DATEFIRST`.

Comment: Yeah i am but i fixed it. answer below

Comment: Dear downvoter....please explain why you have downvoted this question so i can better ask next time? i dont understand whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, after tinkering the convert part was creating an issue so i removed it and it works

```
WHERE  PaymentMethod = 'Credit Card' 
           AND [DueDate] NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(day, (DATEDIFF (day, 4, GETDATE()) / 7) * 7, 3) AND
           DATEADD(day, 4 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
    ORDER BY DueDate desc
```

not even sure why i put that convert part in there